# Cannot change the font size of div class="entry-content" in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I cannot seem to change the font size of **div class="entry-content"** in my WordPress site. I am using the Google Fonts plugin to add CSS Selectors but it does not seem to be changing the font of a post which is too big. I did manage to change fonts of other pages and posts using the Google Fonts plugin (h1.entry-title, p.form-submit) but it is not working for the div class.

Comment: share link of your site or code so that me and other look into your problem and provide you better solution

Comment: @FrontEndCoder, here is the link https://lgediot.000webhostapp.com/monthly-progress-report/staff-members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for change anything on that, like i have change color, font-size and padding

```
article .content-wrap-inner .entry-content p {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. now that i have fixed the font size, i am left with the white blocks and there's a relatively huge gap in between the lines. Please revisit my website https://lgediot.000webhostapp.com/monthly-progress-report/staff-members and have a look.

Comment: you want to reduce the white block gap right ? i have updated my code use 'margin-bottom: 20px;' for that.

Comment: I actually don't want to have the white blocks. how do i remove the white blocks? Also, there is a huge gap in between the lines which is annoying.

Comment: Ok add this css property 'background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);'

Comment: Nothing doing. White background still persists.

Comment: the backgroud color is set on p tag so i am able to remove that with my code. check your code you are doing it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.entry-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

This will target the `<p>` in the `.entry-content` class.

Comment: Thanks but white blocks are still visible. https://lgediot.000webhostapp.com/monthly-progress-report/staff-members